# how to use 4 banks of mp3 files using random picking for the payer source

Tags: xcode

I am looking to use four banks of mp3 files using the random selection.
but want to run these in a timer.
then use the selection for the audio player source
im using about 8000 files of sound snippets

tired various forms of coding

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func (AVAudioPlayer;) {

        NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".mp3" inDirectory:@"."];
        NSString *randomPath = [array objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [array count]];

        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: randomPath] error: NULL;
theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio play];

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

1. To match this opening '{'
   Expected identifier in function declaration
   this at the end
   Expected '}' in class

Comment: am i correct in stating i will have to make an array and list every track name as i seen this mentioned in other posts.

Comment: Your code is unclear. It's mixing Swift & Objective-C. "func (AVAudioPlayer;)" is not valid, etc.

Comment: thank you. ok so best to keep in Swift or Objective-c. im new to xcode  and swift.